# How do I remove rows with duplicate values except those that contains null end empty values?

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I want to use power query to remove rows with duplicate values in a column containing e-mail addresses.
But I do not want to remove rows with duplicate null values or duplicate empty cells.

How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a different solution to the problem.

1. Create a custom column with values from a index column if the email column was emtpty/null but from the email column if it was not empty/null.
2. Remove duplicate rows from the newly created column.
3. Remove the custom column.

Worked fine with me!

I thought that I should share the solution if anyone else can be helped by it.

Answer (score 2):

Split the table in records with nulls/"" and other records.
Remove duplicate emails from the latter table.
Append both tables.

```
let
    Source = Input,
    Empties = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [Email] = null or [Email] = ""),
    Others = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [Email] <> null and [Email] <> ""),
    RemovedDuplicateEmails = Table.Distinct(Others, {"Email"}),
    Appended = Table.Combine({RemovedDuplicateEmails,Empties})
in
    Appended
```

Comment: I tried to implement your code but failed miserably. :-P Is it possible to do this without using the Advanced editor? I am a self-proclaimed n00b and prefer to use the GUI elements of the Power Query Editor.

Comment: You can create a separate query for Empties. In the final query you remove empty emails, remove duplicate emails and then choose Append Queries and append table Empties.